# Consume XML from Kafka topic

Tags: xml, apache-kafka

I need to consume XML type from Kafka topic. After reading through few resources I came to conclusion I might have to write my own "serializer". However I am totally lost on

- How to write such serializer (for value) in first place? and
- How to inject this serializer in Kafka configuration (not just assign class name in spring.deserializer.value.deegate.class)

Comment: Do you use Kafka via Spring, and do you consider using [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) from native client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With raw Kafka client (org.apache.kafka.kafka-clients) it's pretty simple:

1. Implement an `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer` interface. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-custom-serializer) is a tutorial. In a nutshell, you have to implement single method that turns `byte[]` into object of any class you like. Do all xml stuff here and return a parsed xml. Lets say the implementation is named `XmlDeserializer`.
2. Use `KafkaConsumer` constructor with a [3-arg](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Map,org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer,org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer)) signature and pass a deserializer into it: `new KafkaConsumer(props, keyDeserializer, new XmlDeserializer())`. Use `keyDeserializer` you need, there are plenty predifined of them, for example, `new StringDeserializer()`

That's all. You will get a `KafkaConsumer` typed with classes representing parsed key and value. Every `poll()` would return objects of that classes. Your `XmlDeserializer` would be called automatically under the hood.

If using Spring Kafka, you probably create `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` as a bean. In step 2) pass `new XmlDeserializer()` as a constructor parameter.

Also, instead of passing `new XmlDeserializer()` to a constructor (either `KafkaConsumer` or `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory`) you could put deserializer's class name into props: `props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, XmlDeserializer.class)` .

Comment: I build the deserializer however I am getting "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')...". I tried both ObjectMapper and XmlMapper. What I might be still missing?

Comment: @αƞjiβ Well, that's a question related to your xml parser implementation and not related to Kafka at all. ObjectMapper works with json (at least by default). To investigate this one need your deserializer implementation and an input String.

Comment: Yes I fixed the mapper issue and everything working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How do you currently read XML data that isn't a file?

Just use that, and configure your consumer with `ByteArrayDeserializer` or `StringDeserializer`.

The only thing a custom class would do is wrap the same functions you'd use with the other two.